# Integrating with Jira for software with different redirect URLs per installation

Tags: authentication, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm looking into Jira integration for users of our software and trying to figure out the canonical/best way to do it for our use case. That use case is:

- Every customer company has their own instance of our software, which occasionally syncs some data with a central hub but in general runs independently. Each customer instance runs a web server but it may be behind a firewall etc.
- From within our software, we would like to be able to automatically create Jira issues when particular events happen, or when a user of the product presses a button. The Jira issue should be created on the customer's own Jira instance (so one way or another an admin will need to go through some sort of process to connect the company's Jira instance to our software). I think actual user impersonation would be unideal here - it would make the most sense if these issues were simply shown as created by our software/app, though if user impersonation was the only way to do it that wouldn't have to be a dealbreaker.
- We don't need to add any functionality to the Jira UI or receive any webhooks, just for our software to be able to create Jira issues.

It looked to me initially like what we wanted was a Connect app. But after reading some of the documentation, it sounds like Connect apps have a single manifest that needs to be at a publicly accessible URL, with a single hardcoded webhook URL, and can only be installed from the Atlassian Marketplace unless the whole Jira instance is in development mode (if I'm understanding correctly?), which doesn't make a lot of sense for this use case - the user needs to be able to connect the app for their specific instance of our software, which is going to be hosted on a different server with entirely different URLs than someone else's installation.

Next I looked into OAuth 3LO, though it looked like that could exclusively be used in a user-impersonating manner - but also there, each individual app created in the developer console appears to be meant to have a single redirect URL, and attempts to authenticate would presumably be rejected if they submitted different redirect URLs. Thus, it sounds like to use the OAuth method, each customer would have to create their own app for their instance using the developer console.

It looks like Jira does offer the ability to call the API with basic authentication using an API token, so we could ask the customer to give an Atlassian account e-mail and generate an API token, but as noted in the documentation this method is less secure, would involve manual hassle for the user and would presumably also inherently involve user impersonation.

In theory we could do something like a single Connect app with a manifest hosted on the central server, handle and store installations there, and then have customer instances retrieve that information when they sync. But this seems a clunky solution, and I'm not sure I like the idea of storing the Jira credentials for customers somewhere other than their own instance that they have control over. Is there a better way that I haven't spotted?